# ошибка "no database selested" но подключился правильно!

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

выучил php, mysql, хотел попрактиковаться, делаю форму входа, проверяю наличие 
введенного логина на сервере, подключил все 100% правильно, делаю - не выходит, смотрю туториал, переписываю 1 в 1 но всегда одна ошибка -  no database selested, помогите плз)0))

```
$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST["login"]);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mybase");
$mysqli-> query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = $login");
echo mysql_error();

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['login'];


$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Точно ли наша БД называется **mybase** ? Если уверены в этом то могу посоветовать попробовать после **$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mybase");** выполнить **$mysqli-> query ("USE mybase'");**

Comment: выполнил, ошибка та же.. база точно "mybase"

Comment: А почему вы делаете подключение с помощью драйвера mysqli (обратите внимание на букву `i` в конце) и далее используете функции, начинающиеся на `mysql_` (буквы `i` нет !!!) это функции от разных драйверов и совместно работать не могут. После того как перейдете на них будет ошибка, потому что login не заключен в кавычки, а когда вы поставите кавычки будут sql-инъекции, так как htmlspecialchars вас не спасет. используйте подготовленные выражения и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST["login"]);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mybase");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '".$mysqli->escape_string ($login)."'");
echo $mysqli->error;

$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['login'];


$mysqli->close();
```

Правильно сказал @Mike, то что mysql != mysqli. Разные драйвера, разные функции, но синтаксис такой же, за исключением ООП в mysqli

Comment: ошибка пропала, но теперь проблема другая, я ввожу в форму логин, все подключено, но не выводит абсолютно ничего

Comment: ааа все понял, не выводит потому что весь код был в if ($error = false){...}; записал if ($error == false){...}; и все работает, спасибо))

Comment: @shumik_UA, обращайтесь)